# Does Twilio Salesforce Helper Library support the new Passthrough API

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, twilio

I am working on setting up a Salesforce Helper Library to send SMS's from Salesforce using Apex. I am able to send SMS's 1 by 1 using the information from their documentation.

I came across an article about their new API feature: Passthrough API which lets us send bulk SMS's using their API.
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html

I would like to know if this feature is supported for Salesforce Helper Library ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an implementation that would allow us to access the Passthrough API from Apex. Currently waiting for Twilio for Salesforce to release as it has out of box functionality to send Bulk SMS from Apex.